# Rails 6 Testing - Initializers and dynamic data with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I'm currently writing tests for my Rails application using the default Minitest framework and it's working quite fine. The only problem I have that my configuration initializer is run (I guess) every test twice and I can't figure out why this happens.

So, I have an initializer which sets some config parameters from the database for my application:

```
# config/initializers/load_application_settings.rb

Rails.configuration.after_initialize do
    if defined?(::Rails::Server) && !Rails.env.test?
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.header_title = "WebMenue | #{Configuration.first.clinicName}"
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.clinic_name = Configuration.first.clinicName
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.clinic_location = Configuration.first.city
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.proxy_server = Configuration.first.request_server
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.order_time = Configuration.first.orderTime.strftime('%H:%M')
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.repeating_period = Configuration.first.repeatMealTime
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.clinic_iban = Configuration.first.iban
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.clinic_bic = Configuration.first.bic
        WebMenueNew::Application.config.clinic_bank = Configuration.first.bank
    end
end
```

I tried to wrap it witht he `if !Rails.env.test?` condition, but it doesn't seem to work. In my controller test, I tried to initialize the value in the setup method and destroy all params in the teardown method:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    Rails.configuration.clinic_name = "BDH-Klinik Braunfels"
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "WebMenue | BDH-Klinik Braunfels"
  end

  test "should be valid external login" do
    post login_path, params: { session: { using_ldap: false, username: @user.email, password: "valid_password" } }
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirected_to @user
  end

  teardown do
    Configuration.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Even if i move it out of the setup method and into the test method for the new action, it always produces two record in the test database and I get the following error:

> Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
>   PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "configurations_pkey"
>           DETAIL:  Key (id)=(980190962) already exists.

In my new view for the sessions controller I set the title of the application dynamically, that's why I need the parameter:

```
<% content_for(:title) { "WebMenue | #{Rails.configuration.clinic_name}" } %>
```

Is there any workaround so that the initializer is not run on test suites? Or am I missing something? I'm relatively new to testing in Rails so don't be too hard :).

Comment: One thing you really need to consider here is that initializers are run on startup and not per request so this won't work if you are using the database to make the configuration end user configurable. In order for the configuration to be reloaded you would have to restart the rails server. If you want to store the configuration in the database don't go the initializers route. Just access the value straight from the db and then later add caching for performance.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I deleted the initializer and changed the code accordingly, but still the same issue :/

Comment: Don't use `Rails.configuration` then which is really only meant for configuration that is deploy time and not runtime. Instead create your own `current_configuration` method that returns the current config from the db/cache. You need to put on your thinking cap on and do some research on multitenency and you'll find a more suitable solution.